# Metatrader Plugin: what is it?

Tags: plugins, metatrader4, metatrader5

What is Metatrader plugin? I have seen the term in several promotions and articles. What was described in these articles was a species expert with inserts of libraries in other languages ​​(not MQL4 / 5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plugin is usually referred to as a c++ extension that runs in the MT server it self.

Just like the meta manager api, that allows you to extend the operations of the platform as a manager, an MT plugin allows you to extent the actual trading logic of the server. Of course it goes without saying you would need access to the actual server to deploy one.

Comment: So, it means you should be a broker to develop MT plugins?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. Or you can be a developer selling plugins to brokers, however, you would still need to get your hands on a server somehow at least for testing.

Comment: Is it possible to do trading via a MT plugin? It doesnt seem possible using the MT manager api.

Comment: You can do trading with both. The server being more perfomat. Also depends on your definition of trading in this scenario